# Default value for int in text field

Tags: java

I want to change default value for `int` property to **empty field** not **0**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Integer` class and not int for that.
An `int` will always be initialized to **0** It can't be null.

Comment: FYI- `Integer` is wrapper class for primitive type `int`.

Comment: More than 2 years old topic @HarryJoy  .____.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal yes, just trying to push it more close to perfect answer.